# Can I change itinerary after getting a visa?

Tags: visas, transit-visas

Traveling from Thailand via (non Schengen Route) to Cy.

If I have gotten a visa but the itinerary was via Dubai. Is it ok if I change the flight and travel via Bahrain instead?

Comment: Does your landing port (entry point in the Schengen area) changes ? If not doesn't matter.

Comment: @OlaStröm please do not write "visa" in all caps.  There is no reason to do so, as it is just an ordinary word.

Comment: When you say "Cy" do you mean cyprus?

Answer (score 4):

They dont care about the '*via*' part, as long as you do in Schengen area what you told them you will do and they allowed you to do.

You can transit anywhere, take any allowed airline.